# ActivityIndicator Stalls

Tags: c++builder, activity-indicator

I'm running a lengthy routine in C++Builder that needs an ActivityIndicator to satisfy the user while the routine is running. As part of troubleshooting, I set the AI to Animate = True in the Object Inspector of the IDE so that the AI runs when the app starts. But the AI stalls when I click a button to run the lengthy routine. It begins running again when the routine finishes. Is there a way to make AI run while the routing is running?

Comment: I began by setting Animate = True at the start of the lengthy routine and setting it to False at the end of the lengthy routine. The result was that the ActivityIndicator never appeared. Hence, as an experiment, I set it to True in the IDE as I explained. The problem is that the AI DOES NOT RUN while the lengthy routine is running.

Comment: I would suggest running your lengthy routine in a separate thread.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are running the lengthy routine in the context of the main UI thread.  If so, then your routine is blocking the main UI thread's message loop from processing UI-related messages, including ones used by the ActivityIndicator.

You should run the lengthy routine in the context of a separate thread instead.  You can use `TThread` or `TTask` for that purpose.  You can create the thread and start the ActivityIndicator, and then have the thread notify the main UI thread when it is finished so you can stop the ActivityIndicator.

If you don't want to run your routine in a separate thread (or can't, ie if it is using something that has thread-affinity to the UI thread), then you can break up the routine into smaller functions that you can queue up asynchronously with `TThread.ForceQueue()` or equivalent, so that you return control to the main UI message loop in between functions while the routine is running.

If you don't want to do that (ie, because it is too much work to break up the routine's code), then you could simply call `Application.ProcessMessages()` periodically while the routine is running.  But this is generally not advisable to do, as it can cause subtle (or not so subtle) problems in your code if you are not careful with it.  A slightly less intrusive approach would be to call the ActivityIndicator's `Update()` method (and/or the Form's `Update()` method) instead, so it can process any pending paint messages, at least.  But that won't process timer messages used for animation, for instance.

Rule of thumb: *NEVER* block the UI thread!

Comment: Using a thread sounds right. If I can isolate the lengthy routine from anything else my app is doing, like running the ActivityIndicator, my problem is solved. Alas, I haven't ever had to use threads in my programming life, so I'm ignorant about them. Maybe you can suggest a way to proceed.

I must pass two arrays (wchar_t and char) to a threaded routine that interacts with VCL objects. Can you point me to a resource that explains how to implement such a thread? Thanks.

Comment: Look at the TThread and TTask classes, as I mentioned in my answer. They are documented, and there are plenty of online tutorials about them. However, you can't interact with VCL UI controls in a worker thread, so the worker thread will have to synchronize with the main UI thread when accessing them. If your routine is doing a lot of UI work, then a worker thread may not be the best choice. Hard to say for sure since you didn't post any of your code yet.